# Powershell - SPOConnect throws error when connecting to a sharepoint SITE

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I'm having trouble connecting to my share point site.  I belong to an to an organization and was tasked to create a community page/sub site thats customized.

I use the connection string from the API

Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential

except that I'm not connecting to our main orginzations sharepoint site,  but sort of a subsite under it.

my URL basically looks like https://orginizationsite.sharepoint.com/sites/NameOfSubSite

and i get thrown this is not a tenant site.

Are we even able to customize these kinds of sites" or do i basically need admin level access to the organizations share point?

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/introduction-sharepoint-online-management-shell?view=sharepoint-ps

> To use SharePoint Online PowerShell commands, you must be a SharePoint
>   Online global administrator.
>
> Before you can run SharePoint Online commands, you must install the
>   SharePoint Online Management Shell module and connect to the
>   SharePoint Online service. For more information, see Connect
>   SharePoint Online

If you want to connect to a specific site, you can use the SharePoint PnP Powershell module to connect with your regular credentials, but the administrator may have disabled Powershell access for non-admins.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 1):

To use [connect-spoService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/connect-sposervice?view=sharepoint-ps) you need to provide SharePoint Admin Url and use the SharePoint Tenant Admin url.

You can not use the regular SharePoint site for connecting as this powerShell is for admin. Once you connected then you can query against any site collection in the tenant.

but if your requirement is just with one specific site collection and you dont have tenant admin credentials. you should use the [SharePoint PnP powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps), all you need SharePoint site collection admin.